# Android - Json without tags - Parsing

Tags: android, json

How can I parse json from the URL? below is my json structure which does not has tags.

```
[{"channelId":"0465CDBE","channelName":"ATV2"},{"channelId":"06E6923B1","channelName":"Phoenix"},{"channelId":"07B4FB7ed","channelName":"N24"},{"channelId":"115B73E39","channelName":"ORF2"},
```

Comment: Not valid JSON.. please post valid JSON the last `]` character is missing

Comment: look at my answer and if it solves your query then mark it as an answer

Comment: I have to get json from URL. I m having problem in getting data from URL. Can you please guide me? URL is http://5.39.219.67/~tvinfo/tvguide/box/getchannellist?mediagroupId=9c476522-d771-4fcd-ae21-34b302c04e46

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get the `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<jArr.length;i++)
{
String jChannel = jArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("channelId");
 String jChannelName = jArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("channelName");

//you can now play with these variables or add to some list or do whatever you like.
}
```

Comment: I have to get json from URL. I m having problem in getting data from URL. Can you please guide me? URL is http://5.39.219.67/~tvinfo/tvguide/box/getchannellist?mediagroupId=9c476522-d771-4fcd-ae21-34b302c04e46

Answer (score 0):

The outer object is a JSONArray, so you can iterate it with a "for". 
Inside your json array, you have simple json objects. You can parse it by key or iterate the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can user json object and get the value with getJSONArray
examples:

```
testob = {"channelId":"07B4FB7ed","channelName":"N24"}, {"channelId":"115B73E39","channelName":"ORF2"},

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(testob);             
JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");              
JSONObject jsonProductData = dataArray.getJSONObject(0);
```